# Cell color of WPF DataGrid back to the default

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I'm using buildin WPF DataGrid in .net 4.

I can set the background of a DataGridCell programatically like below.

```
DataGridCell dgc = this.GetCell(i, j);  //GetCell is extension func
dgc.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
```

My question is, how can i remove the background color i set and back to the default?
By "default" I mean the default transparent background with the blueish color when the cell is selected.
If i just set back the background of the cell like below,

```
dgc.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

then, it does not become blueish when it is selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dgc.ClearValue(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty);
```

Comment: It seems SO does not allow me to accept an answer in 10 mins.